# FPDF class - Too large columns not manageable in single row

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf

I used inbuilt FPDF to generate a PDF.

I was facing a problem to display approx. 40 columns in a single row. The columns neither get displayed i next row nor they get wrapped, they got cut at the end of the page.
I got this problem resolved by using:

```
// Array to set page size
$a = array(312,1200);

//Add first page
$pdf->AddPage('L',$a);
```

This makes resolution of my table very small as per my requirement, but i am facing problem while i am printing this page. As i can increase resolution in viewing PDF but not while printing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create User Defined Page Size if you declared units before:

```
$pdf = new FPDF('L', 'in', array(100, 50));// page 100"x50"
$pdf->addPage();
```

or

```
$pdf = new FPDF('L', 'in');// inches defined
$pdf->addPage('L', array(100, 50));// page 100"x50"
```

User Manual:

http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/fpdf.htm

http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/addpage.htm

Comment: hey... thanx for the information. but this exactly cant work for me as reducing my page size does not solves my problem. I need to print it clearly with a perfect resolution.

Comment: can you upload the example page if it is not TOP SECRET for visual review?

Comment: yes i can but what is the way to upload here... or is dere any oder way.

Comment: kazumov-at-gmail-dot-com will be OK